# R function to detect unused function arguments

Tags: r

I'm looking for an R function that detects all the functions in an R package that have formal arguments that are not used in the body of the function. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the checkUsagePackage("packagename", all=TRUE) in the codetools package should check this.  It (among other things) tests "warnings about unused formal parameters".  The devtools::check() function might automatically invoke checkUsagePackage().